# Prisma with mariaDB: strange cache issue

Tags: caching, mariadb, prisma

I am using prisma with mariaDB whit in my application. The app does a lot of equal request to the database. However, sometimes i got from database records that are just being delete, multiple times. This got me thinking that prisma or mariaDB have some type of cache to resolve multiple equal queries. I want to disable that.
Any idea on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Hey, just ran into a similar issue - were you able to fix that?

Comment: @Vaviloff i'm sorry, i didn't find any solution. You should try to check the prisma docs, maybe they added something that can solve the issue for you.

Comment: same here but for mysql